# How to use the strategy pattern with managed objects

Tags: cdi, strategy-pattern

I process messages from a queue.  I use data from the incoming message to determine which class to use to process the message; for example origin and type.  I would use the combination of origin and type to look up a FQCN and use reflection to instantiate an object to process the message.  At the moment these processing objects are all simple POJOs that implement a common interface.  Hence I am using a strategy pattern.

The problem I am having is that all my external resources (mostly databases accessed via JPA) are injected (@Inject) and when I create the processing object as described above all these injected objects are null.  The only way I know to populate these injected resources is to make each implementation of the interface a managed bean by adding @stateless.  This alone does not solve the problem because the injected members are only populated if the class implementing the interface is itself injected (i.e. container managed) as opposed to being created by me.

Here is a made up example (sensitive details changed)

```
public interface MessageProcessor
{
   public void processMessage(String xml);
}

@Stateless
public VisaCreateClient implements MessageProcessor
{
   @Inject private DAL db;
   …
}
public MasterCardCreateClient implements MessageProcessor…
```

In the database there is an entry "visa.createclient" = "fqcn.VisaCreateClient", so if the message origin is "Visa" and the type is "Create Client" I can look up the appropriate processing class.  If I use reflection to create VisaCreateClient the db variable is always null.  Even if I add the @Stateless and use reflection the db variable remains null.  It's only when I inject VisaCreateClient will the db variable get populated.  Like so:

```
@Stateless
public QueueReader
{
   @Inject VisaCreateClient visaCreateClient;
   @Inject MasterCardCreateClient masterCardCreateClient;
   @Inject … many more times

   private Map<String, MessageProcessor> processors...

   private void init()
   {
      processors.put("visa.createclient", visaCreateClient);
      processors.put("mastercard.createclient", masterCardCreateClient);
      … many more times
   }
}
```

Now I have dozens of message processors and if I have to inject each implementation then register it in the map I'll end up with dozens of injections.  Also, should I add more processors I have to modify the QueueReader class to add the new injections and restart the server; with my old code I merely had to add an entry into the database and deploy the new processor on the class path - didn't even have to restart the server!

I have thought of two ways to resolve this:

1. Add an init(DAL db, OtherResource or, ...) method to the interface that gets called right after the message processor is created with reflection and pass the required resource.  The resource itself was injected into the QueueReader.
2. Add an argument to the processMessage(String xml, Context context) where Context is just a map of resources that were injected into the QueueReader.

But does this approach mean that I will be using the same instance of the DAL object for every message processor?  I believe it would and as long as there is no state involved I believe it is OK - any and all transactions will be started outside of the DAL class.

So my question is will my approach work?  What are the risks of doing it that way?  Is there a better way to use a strategy pattern to dynamically select an implementation where the implementation needs access to container managed resources?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Isn't this what jms does for you with topics?

Comment: It might - I have only looked briefly into it just now, can you recommend a good resource to learn more?

Answer (score 0):

In a similar problem statement I used an extension to the processor interface to decide which type of data object it can handle. Then you can inject all variants of the handler via instance and simply use a loop:

```
public interface MessageProcessor
{
   public boolean canHandle(String xml);
   public void processMessage(String xml);
}
```

And in your queueReader:

```
@Inject
private Instance<MessageProcessor> allProcessors;

public void handleMessage(String xml) {
    MessageProcessor processor = StreamSupport.stream(allProcessors.spliterator(), false)
        .filter(proc -> proc.canHandle(xml))
        .findFirst()
        .orElseThrow(...);
    processor.processMessage(xml);
}
```

This does not work on a running server, but to add a new processor simply implement and deploy.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Instance<> can you elaborate on what that is?

Comment: Basically a means to iterate over all matching beans or create new ones. The reference doc probably can explain that better than me: https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/2.0/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html